# how to get true or false using execute() in Java Statement

Tags: java, execute

I have **Statement** object called **stmt**, Connection object **conn**.

```
stmt = conn.createStatement();
boolean b = stmt.execute("INSERT INTO employee VALUES('E001', 'Smith')")
```

But this always produce **false**. I want **true** if above query executed successfully and **false** if the query fails executing. How can I achieve that result using **execute()** method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How can I achieve that result using execute() method.

You can't. It will only return `true` if the result has a `ResultSet`. If there is a problem with your insertion, the method will throw an exception. From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute%28java.lang.String%29):

> boolean execute(String sql) throws SQLException
>
> Returns:
>
> **true if the first result is a ResultSet object**; false if it is an update count or there are no results
>
> Throws:
>
> SQLException - if a database access error occurs, this method is called on a closed Statement, the method is called on a PreparedStatement or CallableStatement
>
> SQLTimeoutException - when the driver has determined that the timeout value that was specified by the setQueryTimeout method has been exceeded and has at least attempted to cancel the currently running Statement

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was confused a lot. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [executeUpdate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)) method on the `Statement`. It should return you a int indicating the number of rows.

Answer (score 2):

`Statement.ececute()` will return true if the first result is a ResultSet object, false if it is an update count or there are no results

You can use

> **int executeUpdate(String sql)**

returns

> 1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements
>   or
>
> 2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing

[Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html)

Answer (score 0):

You cant if it is not a select query.
This is what said in the doc

```
Returns:  
true if the first result is a ResultSet object; false if it is an update count or there are no results`.
```

You will get a result set when you give a select query not when insert or update, you will get false always in case of these type of query .
Now to make it sure if its run successfully or not i guess working with e `Exceptions` will help you

Using `executeUpdate()` will give you the row count so you can use that to predict.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing an insert statement, If there is an resultset that has values returning from the execute statement there will be a result. [Check the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute(java.lang.String))